# Find all positive integers satisfying $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2} =k $

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers satisfying 
$$\frac{2^n+1}{n^2} =k $$

where $k$ is a integer.

I can't just come up with a solution.

Comment: You should study the intersection of $y=2^n$ and $y=kn^2-1$, varying $k$ (and $n$). For example, if $k=3$, then you get the solution $n=1$.

Comment: As I told I couldn't come up with any solution

Comment: I suggest to draw $y=n^2-1$, $y=2n^2-1$ and $y=3n^2-1$ against $y=2^n$, for all $n>1$ (integers). What you are looking for is integer intersection points between the 2 curves. Can you find them in these cases? If $k>3$ then, looking at your diagram, you can infer that...

Comment: Could you just post it in the answer with the graph

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is extremely famous in world of Olympiad mathematics(It appeared in IMO 1990 , Problem-3) . This problem is famous, because it is also very easily solvable by use of [Lifting the exponent lemma](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) If you don't know about this lemma yet, then read this article, you will never regret.

Otherwise, see [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln903.html).

Comment: Buddy the page doesn't exist

Comment: edited, thanks :)

Comment: If you want to see the proof using, LTE 
then see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3217312#p3217312

Comment: Great help man thnx

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the Landau-Ostrowski Diophantine equation
$$
ay^2+by+c=dx^n
$$
with $x=2$, $y=n$, $c=-1$, $b=0$, $d=1$ and $a=k$, i.e., $kn^2-1=2^n$. It has the solutions $(n,k)=(1,3),(3,1)$. This follows, for example, from Theorem $L$ in the paper [*On the number of solutions of the generalized Ramanujan-Nagell equation*](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/bushodef.ps) by Y. Bugeaud.

In general, it has at most finitely many solutions $x,y$ $n\ge 3$, if $a,d\neq 0$ and $b^2-4ad\neq 0$, see Landau, Ostrowski: Proc. London Math. Soc. 19, no. 2, 276–280, (1920).

Answer (score 0):

We want to find those $n\in\mathbb N$ (we exclude the $0$) s.t.

$$2^n=kn^2-1,$$

with integer $k$. To do so, we introduce the curves $y_1(n)=2^n$ and $y_k(n)=kn^2-1$, with real nonnegative variable $n$ and we study their intersections. We are interested in integer intersections. Let us do this.

- $k = 0$

We are left to  solve $2^n=-1$, which has no solution.

- $k=1$

Let us study the integer solutions of $2^n=n^2-1$. It is easy to see that $n=3$ is the only solution. Uniqueness is proven geometrically; $y_1(n)=n^2-1$ is a monotone increasing continuous function, with $y_1(3)=2^3$, as claimed; it lies below $y(n)=2^n$ for all $n<3$, while for all $n>3$ we have $y_1(n)>2^n$ (draw a diagram to convince yourself).

- $k=2$

Let us study the integer solutions of $2^n=2n^2-1$. To do so we notice that  $y_2(1)=1$, while $y(1)=2$, and $y_2(2)=7$, while $y(2)=4$. As both functions are monotone increasing (and continuous), then their intersection point lies between $1$ and $2$: as it cannot be an integer, then we have no solution in this case.

- $k=3$

This case is easier than the previous one, as  $y_3(1)=2=y(1)$. So $n=1$ is an integer solution and it is the only one due to geometrical reasons as above (draw a picture).

- $k>3$

We are left to solve $2^n=kn^2-1$ with $k>3$; as $y_k(1)=k-1>y(1)=2$ (we are considering $k>3$), then the intersection point between $y_k(n)$ and $y(n)$ lies between $0$ and $1$. It cannot be an integer and we have no solution in this case.

Comment: Is there any other way doing it apart from graphs

Comment: Yes; the existence of solutions is easy to do case by case; the uniqueness follows from monotonicity and continuity of the 2 functions involved. The graphs allows you to keep track of progression. I hope it helps

Comment: Are you sure about the case $k>3$? It seems to me that $y_4(x)=y(x)$ has two intersections.

Comment: Which intersections did you find? Are they integers?

Comment: I will extend my answer adding some details.

Comment: $2^x=4x^2-1$ has a solution around $x=8$.